# how to determine what address is invalid for PCI/PCIe memory space

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-driver, pci, pci-e

I'm writing a PCIe device driver and want to add a sanity check for validity of I/O addresses in memory-mapped space, i.e. that in case a driver user provides invalid address, a driver API that reads/writes in PCI memory-mapped space would return error. The PCI/PCIe spec doesn't define which addresses are considered invalid.

By a driver user I mean another kernel module that might use my API exposed via `EXPORT_SYMBOL()`.

**UPDATE**

What I have on PCI hardware is as follows:

BAR0 register `0xCDE00000 & 0xFFFFFFF0 = 0xCDE00000` (mask out info bits from BAR register). Now derive the size of region pointed to by BAR0:

- save original value of BAR
- write a value of all 1's to BAR register
- read it back
- mask the information bits
- perform a bitwise NOT and increment the value by 1
- restore the original BAR value

Size value is 0x100000, that is 1M, which makes all offsets 20-bits long, so to validate an offset, we can simply apply mask 0xfffff:

```
if (offset & 0xfffff)
   /* offset is valid */
```

Comment: To access the device you have to use MMIO space which is provided by `pcim_iomap_regions()`. It reads information from PCI BARs.

Comment: The question is not how to access pci space, but how to validate the input address.

Comment: I didn't get why user even shall do that, but they have to supply relative address (offset) to the PCI BAR you are using to access the device. BAR has start address and length. When user supplies offset you may validate it vs. length. Usually you may just mask it with offset mask and it will be always correct.

Comment: May be I didn't put my question clearly, I updated my post.

Comment: Hmm… I really didn't get what you are talking about. Your device has a memory mapped region or even regions that usually comes from PCI BARs. Correct? If so, the BARs have length of their resources that can limit the actual **offset** used by *users of the driver*. Maybe you provide a little example in C?

Comment: @Andy, thanks for feedback. I updated my post with possible solution.

Comment: Length is already encoded in the PCI BARs. You just get it via `resource_size_t len = pci_resource_len(device, bar);`